# Split lines with multiple words in Python

Tags: python, text-files, text-processing

I have a (very ugly) txt output from an SQL query which is performed by external system that I can't change. Here is the output example:

```
FruitName      Owner             OwnerPhone
=============  ================= ============
Red Apple      Sr Lorem Ipsum    123123
Yellow Banana  Ms Dolor sir Amet 456456
```

As you can see, the `FruitName` column and the `Owner` column may consists of few words and there's no fixed pattern in how many words could be in these columns. If I use `line.split()` to make array on each line Python, it will remove all the whitespace and make the array become like this:

```
['Red', 'Apple', 'Sr', 'Lorem', 'Ipsum', '123123']
['Yellow', 'Banana', 'Ms', 'Dolor', 'sir', 'Amet', '456456']
```

The question is, how can I split it properly into output like this:

```
['Red Apple', 'Sr Lorem Ipsum', '123123']
['Yellow Banana', 'Ms Dolor sir Amet', '456456']
```

I'm a newbie in Python and I dont know if such thing is possible or not. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the row of equals signs part of the output? If so, that'd be a very easy way to get the column widths. You can then extract the fields via slicing.

Comment: first column has length 13 chars so using `line[:13].strip()` you can get it. Similar for other columns. If you use `pandas` then it has `read_fwf` to read files with fixed-width-fields.

Comment: Can you split using regular expression to split when the number of spaces are more than 2?

Comment: the first and second row is not part of the output. I think I'm agree with furas's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns have fixed widths so you can use it and slice lines

```
data = '''FruitName      Owner             OwnerPhone
=============  ================= ============
Red Apple      Sr Lorem Ipsum    123123
Yellow Banana  Ms Dolor sir Amet 456456'''

lines = data.split('\n')

for line in lines[2:]:
    fruit = line[:13].strip()
    owner = line[13:32].strip()
    phone = line[32:].strip()
    print([fruit, owner, phone])
```

More complex solution would use second line - with `===` - to calculate widths for columns and use them in slicing.

Comment: this works for me!!
i took your advise, i used the second line to calculate each column length and use the int value to get substring on the loop. Thanks! very valuable insight

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `====` dividers to your advantage in that you can get slices in all lines corresponding to the start and end indices of each `====` that represents a column:

```
def get_divider_indices(line):
  i, j = 0, line.index(' ')
  indices = []
  while i != -1:
    indices.append((i, j))
    i = line.find('=', j)
    j = line.find(' ', i)
    if j == -1: j = len(line)
  return indices

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  dividers = get_divider_indices(lines[1])
  rows= []
  for line in lines[2:]:
    rows.append([line[s:e].strip() for s, e in dividers])

print(rows)
```

**Output**

```
[['Red Apple', 'Sr Lorem Ipsum', '123123'], ['Yellow Banana', 'Ms Dolor sir Amet', '456456']]
```

Note that you can use [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to get the index of a character in a string (which I use above to get the index of an `=` or a space in the divider line).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others you can use the length of each divider to calculate the length of the `columns`. The following example illustrates just that:

```
rows = list()
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    dividers = lines[1].split() 

    for line in lines[2:]:
        row = []
        prvLength = 0
        for d in dividers:
            start = prvLength
            length = start+len(d)+1
            row.append(line[start:start+length].strip())
            prvLength += length
        rows.append(row)
print(rows)
```

**Output**

```
[['Red Apple', 'Sr Lorem Ipsum', '123123'], ['Yellow Banana', 'Ms Dolor sir Amet', '456456']]
```

---

You can also check if the columns are separated by `TABS`, i.e. `'\t'`. If so, you can just split the `line` of `lines` using `line.split('\t')` which would be much more simple.